# I have a 8k 30fps video, how can I edit it to rotate the content 90deg from X to Y seconds only?

Tags: video, video-editor, video-conversion

I'm currently using KDenlive but it doesn't seem to have a profile for 8K.

I went to a recital and I filmed my video first in the portrait mode then I switched to landscape mode. And so I wanted to rotate only those first 10 minutes.

What free tool can do it in 8k?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? This [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/c-DpcopXwfE?si=BN0ErfzS_wNOuuNR) seems to show how work with 8K video in Shotcut. You should be able to rotate the clip, but that won't change the aspect ratio.

Comment: @user68186 I'm using Ubuntu 22.04